# OneNote 2010 export or report

Tags: reporting, onenote

I have created a smal incident management tool in OneNote 2010.
I'm looking for a way to be able to extract stats from it.
All my pages under 2 sections are build up on a template and have sames fields.

Now I was looking on exporting my NoteBook in access but I have so many images and files inserted in my pages that I can find a way.
Excel is realy not a good format for my incident and file would be way to big.

I'm the only one using this tool (could be used by other but not nesseracy).  Cannot install or request for a real incident program like Chorus Remedy or other.

I'm looking for an idea in order to be able to provide stats to my boss such as how many tickets I have created within the month, how many are resolved, list of user etc....
For now I calculate all manually.

Thank you all.

Comment: Are you looking for a product that can read from OneNote and export the data to something, or are you trying to custom create an application and need assistance with the code?

Comment: Looking for something that is already existing if possible, I don't know how to code or program.  Either a way to extract report from onenote or export my notebook to something that can provide report.  If possible.. I maybe was looking for something web base, but how would I export my data into.. ?